# Migration & Technology Alignment: Sails.js from Wakanda

Tags: sails.js

I am evaluating Sails.js as potentially the most closely aligned alternative for a migration of about four years of development on the Wakanda JS full stack platform.  I would appreciate perspectives from the Sails.js community based on the following overview:

AS-IS:  WakandaDB, Node.js / SSJS / Node Workers / Shared Workers;  Client side:  Angular 5 for Web and for Ionic/Cordova hybrid mobile apps.

Wakanda DB and Wakanda API and dataclass / dataclass method architecture and all of its off the shelf capabilities will no longer be in play.

It seems that Sails.js is the most closely aligned to my current technology stack.  Does the community agree with this?  I understand the community is pretty large, but I do not see evidence of this in terms of books on Amazon (as compared to the Meteor platform for example).

Appreciate perspectives and any references to migration related guides/references.

Kirk

Comment: I can't speak for anything relative to Wakanda as it's the first i've heard of it. This said, I see Sails as something that provides logical structure to an Express project. Yes there is some some complexity involved within this abstraction but ultimately and in most cases you're not really forced to use any of the abstractions that sails provides.

Comment: In that sense, it's a very useful tool as it helps to create some sanity and order in more complex types of projects. There's not much official resources available for Sails and what exists is sort of outdated at this point but the website documentation is decent and gitter is active. Ultimately though, you're working with Node, Express and web sockets, there is plenty of resources out there on these topics. I struggled to find a decent webpack integration for Sails so ended up making my own, you'll likely have to do stuff like this too if you want to get things to work as envisioned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using sails.js professionnaly for four years now.
I worked with version V0.12 and now V1.0.

I've never heard of the Framework Wakanda so i can't tell you if the technology stack match.

All i can say is Sails.JS have strenghs and weaknesses.
I will just give you the cons so you can see if this is a no go for you.

The community is not the most active, a lots of good stuff developed for v0.12 isn't ready for v1.0 after years (i'm thinking of sails-auth and sails-permissions who provide good ACL structure).

He could be to big for small projects but i don't think it's a problem for your needs.

He works great with MongoDB but not that much with other DB system (even if community developed adapters for other DB as postgresql).

And for me the biggest weakness of this framework is his ORM.
This one will play with your nerves, you will have to rewrite some parts like the one who create the criteria of the query from express req and set default limit to your query even if you don't ask it.
I you don't use mongo, don't use the migration script provide by the adapter and build your own with db-migrate.

So i will recommend Sails JS for project with complex API but simple DB structure.

Hope this will help you in your choice ;)